# No char input to scanner creates infinite loop

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

I've got a strange issue (or at least strange to me). I've got a couple if-else-if statements that are causing strange behavior. For context, I'm essentially taking a `char` input using the `Scanner` class and using `Scanner.nextInt().charAt(0)`. This *appears* to work fine if I check for the required characters and input a totally random character (it returns text to the terminal, breaks out, and exits). *However*, if I just hit enter at the `char` prompt, it creates what appears to be an infinite loop (maybe a memory leak?). Attached is the code I'm working on, as well as screenshots of it running in Coderunner2.

Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class phonebill 
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please input the account number: ");
        int acct = sc.nextInt(); // reads arbitrary account number
        System.out.print("Please input service code: ");
        char svc_code = sc.next().charAt(0); // reads service code 
character

    /* the following blocks check for the appropriate service codes.
     * valid codes include p or P for 'Premium' service, and 
     * r or R for regular service. if no valid code is read,
     * the program exits, informing the user to input a valid code.
     */
        if (svc_code == 'p' || svc_code == 'P')
        {
            System.out.print("Please input daytime minutes: ");
            int day_min = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Please input nighttime minutes: ");
            int night_min = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Service code is " + svc_code + " and this condition works.");
        }
        else if (svc_code == 'r' || svc_code == 'R')
        {
            System.out.print("Please input used minutes: ");
            int mins = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Service code is " + svc_code + " and this condition works.");
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Please input a valid service code.");
        }
        System.out.print("That's all for now folks");
    }
}
```

[Code running normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1TMI.png)

[Code being weird](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtBkz.png)

UPDATE: I'm just bad at Java and scanners.

Comment: That is one of the differences between `next()` and `nextLine()`. By default `next()` can't accept empty line as input, because default delimiter is one or more whitespace which includes lineseparators. Since `next()` returns tokens (strings which are separated by delimiter) and you only provides delimiter (line separator generated by Enter key on keyboard) `next()` is still waiting for non-delimiter character(s).

Comment: That makes sense. Not sure why I didn't think of that initially. I'm still early on in the course and I hadn't considered blank input before now, but I suppose they don't really care if it handles blank input. Technically they don't care if it handles wrong input but I felt it should at *least* do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an infinite loop, or a memory leak.

It's just waiting for you to enter a non-empty string.

```
$ java phonebill
Please input the account number: 123
Please input service code: 
















string
Please input a valid service code.
That's all for now folks
```

(The blank lines are where I was just hitting enter. I eventually typed "string", and it stopped).

Comment: To be precise, a token.

Comment: I see. I hadn't even thought about that. I was looking around about the `char` datatype and noticed it was considered primitive, which is why there's no `nextChar()` function in the scanner. I'm not used to how java works yet, though I'm sure most other languages work the same. I suppose there's no way to say something like "if (' ') then close scanner" or anything then, right? I should just be assuming there's input at all?

Comment: @parsec if you want to handle potentially empty strings, use `sc.nextLine()`. You can use `String.startsWith` to check if a potentially empty string starts with a character.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'll look into that. might be worth doing just to avoid any potentially weird things like this happening in the future, or to avoid it playing weird with any automated tests they may have.